# How to find the most repeated word in a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap with Strings already splitted and i want to count the most repeated word in it, print the word and print how many times that word repeats.

Comment: The key? The value? Your attempts please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code please.

Comment: share what you have tried so far

Comment: public String RepeatedWord(){
  String word = "";
  for (String word: words){
   if (test.containsKey(word)){
    test.put(word, test.get(word)+1);
   }
  }
  
  
  return word;
  
 }

Comment: Please don't post your code in a comment. Edit your question instead. And make sure you actually format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's actually pretty easy with Stream api...

```
Map<String, Long> result = List.of("1", "2", "3", "1", "3", "3")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    () -> new TreeMap<String, Long>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                    Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result); // {3=3, 2=1, 1=2}
```